# element tag solve "Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start." error.Why?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating a web application using JSP. Suddenly got `"Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start"` error. I tried different things and find a way to solve it by adding **element tag** in the `web.xml` file. By adding this my application executes without any error.

But this cause me not getting **context-param** value in JSP.
Please help me with the concept behind this.

**Web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
 <jsp-file>WebContent/contextDemo.jsp</jsp-file>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

<context-param>  
<param-name>d</param-name>  
<param-value>sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</param-value>  
</context-param>

</web-app>
</element>
```

**action.html**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="welcome">
<input type="text" name="uname">
<input type="submit" value="go"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Search"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

**contextDemo.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% out.print("Welcome"+request.getParameter("uname")); 
String driver=application.getInitParameter("d");  
out.print("driver name is="+driver);  
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you checked the logs?

Comment: Getting this :** Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException** @Stultuske